# Replace template URL in components based on global constant

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, frontend

Help me find solution for following task:

let's say we have some global constant 'env' and i wanna use this constant to replace template url in components in build time.  For different constant we should use different template url. Each component has template URL by default. For each 'env' constant we can define template URL for some component, if template url not define for component need use default template.

For example:

**The following components use template URL by default:**

```
AppComponent1 -> 'defaultTemplate1'

AppComponent2 -> 'defaultTemplate2'

AppComponent3 -> 'defaultTemplate3'
```

**when we set 'env' constant as 'env_1' i wanna use next templates:**

```
AppComponent1 -> 'env_1Template1'

AppComponent2 -> 'env_1Template2'

AppComponent3 -> 'defaultTemplate3'
```

**for 'env' as 'env_2' need use:**

```
AppComponent1 -> 'env_2Template1'

AppComponent2 -> 'defaultTemplate2'

AppComponent3 -> 'env_2Template3'
```

Comment: By template URL do you mean the component selector? Like `<defaultTemplate1></defaultTemplate1>`?

Comment: No, i mean templateUrl property in @Component decorator

Answer (score 0):

With a lack of details on your current implementation, you could try to do something as follows

Environment config (constants.ts)

```js
export const ENVIRONMENT: string = 'env_1';
```

A random component (child.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as CONFIG from '../constant';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: CONFIG.ENVIRONMENT === 'env_1' ? './child.html' : './child2.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

I've used a basic ternary operation to decide on the template URL. You could make it as complicated as you wish to decide the URL. You could also send the URL path directly from the environment config file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I meant another. If we has environment variables more that two and some component has many specific template by value this global constant.
Let's say some function with parameter 'env' which returns template name if result is undefined we use default template.

"templateUrl: getTemplate(env) ? getTemplate(env)' : './default.html';"

Comment: as result will be great if i can change only global constant to redefine template for all components. I can't find work solution